# swift Invalid Redeclaration

Tags: ios, swift

```
func dropShape() {
        if let shape = fallingShape {
            while detectIllegalPlacement() == false {
                shape.lowerShapeByOneRow()
            }
            shape.raiseShapeByOneRow()
            delegate?.gameShapeDidDrop(self)
        }
    }
```

Hi, I'm taking this Invalid redeclaration of 'dropShape()' so what did I wrong. Can anybody help me

Comment: I guess you have declared `dropShape()` somewhere else in app.

Comment: You have declare two methods with the same name. Also check that you have not declared any variable with `dropShape`.

Comment: Both [redeclaration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27474798/6521116) and [recompile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50148125/6521116) can cause the issue.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

That error message means that you have created two functions with the same name.

[image]

You can not use same name and same signature for function. Yes **function overloading** is there and it means that you can use same name with different parameters. You can create as many function as you want using same name. ***The thumb rule is each overloading function must have different parameters.***

For Example:

```
func dropShape() {        
}

func dropShape(points: CGPoint) {        
}
```

Comment: Simply there is not another answer to this question

Comment: This answer is wrong. You can have different functions with same name in swift. __Function overloading__ works in swift:)

Comment: @Anil Varghese I don't think that's the case

Comment: @Anil Varghese So what do you think it is happening ?

Comment: He declared two functions with __same signature__ not the same name.  I was pointing that:)

Comment: I think the point is that `func thisFunc(param: String)` and `func thisFunc(diffParam: String)` will collide because they have the same signatures despite different parameter names.

Comment: @n8yn8 declare one of them (or both) forcing the name to be entered func thisFunc(diffParam diffParam: String) {

Comment: This answer would be correct for most C-like languages; however, Swift is a bit more lenient. You can, in fact, have multiple function declarations with the same parameter types but different parameter names: `func example(foo: String)` and `func example(bar: String)` would not collide. Furthermore, you can have functions with the exact same parameters AND parameter names if they have different return types: `func example()` and `func example() -> String` would not collide.

Answer (score 34):

I had the same issue, I've solved it by deleting an extra file in the compile sources.

1. Go your project root directory.
2. Go to **Build Phases**.
3. Click on **Compile Sources**, check for a file that has been added twice and delete one of them.

That should solve your problem.

Comment: thanks a lot @J. Koush ! Some times XCode drives me craizy

Comment: this error happened to me after git merge conflicts in the Xcode project file (duplicate .swift source files in Build Phases -> Compile Sources)

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked \o/. I had this problemas after a rebase.

Comment: THIS ONE should be the accepted answer. You saved my day, dude!

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact error message just right now. For me it was a *class* and a *struct* conflict.

For any two declaration of types in the *same* scope, you will get an error e.g. if you use *any* of declare any of the 2 types below, you will get an error

```
class employee{...}
struct employee{...}
func employee(){...}
protocol employee{...}
```

It's not just for classes, structs or func, it's for everything because `func`s, `struct`s, `enum`s, `protocol`s are all **[First class citizens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function)** in Swift

Comment: You should always name your class, structures, enumerations and protocols starting with an uppercase letter.

Comment: Correct. This was just for demonstration purposes...I wanted to show the same issue happens even with function

Answer (score -2):

This error happened when you don't import UIKit and the class name should be unique so make sure to add `import UIKit` and the functions or class has a unique name.