# Invalid redeclaration of UITableViewDataSource method?

Tags: cocoa-touch, swift

I'm trying to implement the required methods of UITableViewDataSource but I'm getting a weird  error:

> "invalid redeclaration of 'tableview(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)'"

However I'm not sure what the problem is. Here are the two relevant lines of code, the declaration of the class and conforming protocols/superclass:

```
class SubjectFormViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource
```

and the function declaration that's triggering the error:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->  UITableViewCell
```

Comment: Apart from redeclaration, recompile the same file will also cause the issue. Refer to [Invalid redeclaration of ****](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50148125/6521116)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have this function twice in your class. Search for it and erase one of them.

Comment: How did I miss that?!

Comment: Just FYI because it just happened to me. It can also be that you are extending subclass B of a class A which is already declaring this method, but copy/pasting the extension you forgot to rename "extension A" in "extension B". Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You might have the same function twice in your class. Remove one of them if that is the case.

Sometimes your class extends a class that has the same function. Then, you must use "override" keyword to modify extended method, or call the method directly without defining in the class.