# Invalid redeclaration of 'CURRENT_USER'

Tags: xcode, swift, macos

I wanted to define a variable for an OS X Application with Swift.

But I always get this error : "Invalid redeclaration of `CURRENT_USER`".

This is what I wrote:

```
var CURRENT_USER: Firebase?
```

I also tried it with func:

```
func var CURRENT_USER: Firebase?
```

Does anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: it says `redeclaration`, either you have this variable in your class or in it's parent

Comment: Is the problem that? `let BASE_URL = "https://macsafe.firebaseio.com"

let FIREBASE_REF = Firebase(url: BASE_URL)

var CURRENT_USER: Firebase?`

Comment: Both redeclaration and recompile can cause the issue. Refer to [Invalid redeclaration of UITableViewDataSource method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27474798/6521116) and [Invalid redeclaration of ****](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50148125/6521116)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EXPLANATION:**

Yes, either:

1) You must have declared `CURRENT_USER` somewhere else in your code already (in the same `Class` or `func`).

2) `CURRENT_USER` is a variable used by a framework.

---

**SOLUTION:**

Just change the name of the var.

Comment: I have defined that var in an other project... Is that the problem?

Comment: In another project ? It depends if the two are linked somehow (if you make requests from one project to the other for example). Anyway, the fix is still the same. Just change the name of your var. Please tell us if that works.

Comment: Yeah but this is strange.. The only definition that is similar to CURRENT_USER is currentUser.

Comment: Then `CURRENT_USER` is a var that exists in a framework you are using.

Answer (score 0):

In `swift`, if you declare the same name if different `.swift` file out of the `class` will cause the issue:`Invalid redeclaration of ''`

Such as:

In `A.swift`:

```
import UIKit

let max_count = 10 // the declare

class A: UIViewController {

}
```

In `B.swift`:

```
import UIKit

let max_count = 10 // there will appear the error!

class B: UIViewController {

}
```

Hope this can help someone!