# Invalid redeclaration of viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, viewdidload

My code is:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var statePicker: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var statePickerBTN: UIButton!

    let states = ["Alaska,Arkansas, Alabama, California, Maine, New York"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        statePicker.dataSource = self
        statePicker.delegate = self
    }

    @IBAction func statePickerButton(_ sender: Any) {
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return states.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return states[row]
    }
}
```

It says that it was "invalid redeclaration of 'viewDidLoad()'

Comment: Both redeclaration and recompile can cause the issue. Refer to [Invalid redeclaration of UITableViewDataSource method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27474798/6521116) and [Invalid redeclaration of ****](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50148125/6521116)

Answer (score 0):

You wrote the function

```
 override func viewdidLoad() {
      super.viewdidLoad()
 }
```

twice in your code. Remove it. It will get resolved

Answer (score 0):

I think you are new to Swift and iOS..Your error clearly shows that  ""invalid redeclaration of 'viewDidLoad()'" you have declared the method viewDidLoad twice. Remove one. we cannot have multiple method with same name and arguments inside a class.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        statePicker.dataSource = self
        statePicker.delegate = self
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
```