# IQKeyboardManager - invalid redeclaration of AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, iqkeyboardmanager

I am trying to use `IQKeyboardManager` in my project but when I add the folder, it triggers an error on in my AppDelegate.swift. It starts at the class line - Invalid redeclaration of 'AppDelegate'. I've tried different approaches to fixing the error but no luck. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I recommend you to install the library via CocoaPods. By the way, please submit your code so I can help you

Comment: Both redeclaration and recompile the same file will also cause the issue. Refer to [Invalid redeclaration of UITableViewDataSource method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27474798/6521116) and [Invalid redeclaration of ****](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50148125/6521116)