# Xcode : Invalid redeclaration of 'ViewController'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, redeclaration

I just finished my app and it was working fine, but all of a sudden after pressing File -> duplicate, I have a message saying

> Invalid redeclaration of 'ViewController'

Please help me out if you can guys? Thank you

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var slideScrollView: UIScrollView!

    @IBOutlet var pageControl: UIPageControl!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        slideScrollView.delegate = self
        let slides:[Slide] = createSlides()
        setupSlideScrollView(slides: slides)
        pageControl.numberOfPages = slides.count
        pageControl.currentPage = 0
        view.bringSubview(toFront: pageControl)
    }

    func createSlides () -> [Slide] {
        let slide1: Slide = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Slide", owner:self, options:nil)?.first as!Slide

        slide1.label.text = "Slide1"

        let slide2: Slide = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Slide", owner:self, options:nil)?.first as!Slide

        slide2.label.text = "Slide2"
        return [slide1, slide2]
    }

    func setupSlideScrollView (slides:[Slide]) {

        slideScrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
        slideScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width * CGFloat(slides.count), height: view.frame.height)
        slideScrollView.isPagingEnabled = true


        for i in 0 ..< slides.count {

            slides[i].frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.width * CGFloat(i), y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
            slideScrollView.addSubview(slides[i])
        }
    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let pageIndex = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x/view.frame.width)
        pageControl.currentPage = Int(pageIndex)

    }

}
```

Comment: The problem isn't the implementation of `ViewController` but rather that you duplicated the file, so it's now finding two different files that define `ViewController`. You need to either remove one of them, or alter one of them to define a class with a name other than `ViewController` (e.g. `SecondViewController` or `DetailsViewController` or whatever).

Comment: Yes! I just figured it out. Thank you for helping me!

Comment: Both redeclaration and recompile can cause the issue. Refer to [Invalid redeclaration of UITableViewDataSource method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27474798/6521116) and [Invalid redeclaration of ****](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50148125/6521116)

Answer (score 6):

This error means that you have another file declared with:

```
class ViewController...
```

You might have changed the filename, for example to ViewControllerTwo.swift but make sure to change the class declaration too.

Comment: Worked it out now. Thanks Rashwan!

Comment: we need to change the class name from ViewController.

Answer (score 1):

Did you press **save** after clicking the **duplicate**? The message is already telling you a solution. You need to find the other class you have that has the name `ViewController`.

Two steps may help:

1. Search `ViewController` in your Xcode's **Find Navigator** (search)
2. Browse your project folder and search for the duplicated .swift file.

Comment: Hey Glenn! Thanks for taking the time to help me. I pasted the whole code there. I tired to find it but had no luck

Comment: Good to hear that, J.BAT. You can select an answer to your (this) question/thread :).