# Invalid redeclaration of ****

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

**Note**: I've search a lot,  such as [Invalid redeclaration of UITableViewDataSource method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27474798/6521116) not apply to my case. For there is no duplicate file or class in my code.

I've only one AppDelegate.swift file in my project and only one class `AppDelegate` in the file. But I've got

[image]

I also have below code in the AppDelegate.swift file. I get below error.

```
extension Data {
    var hexString: String {
        return withUnsafeBytes {(bytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) -> String in
            let buffer = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: bytes, count: count)
            return buffer.map {String(format: "%02hhx", $0)}.reduce("", { $0 + $1 })
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

**Note**, I've grep the duplicate class or variable declaration in my project, and there is once declaration in the code.

Comment: You declare same name of String. You have to change var hexString to Some another name in "Appdelegate" or Extension of DATA.

Comment: @RakeshPatel I've grep the `hexString` in my project, there is only declaration.

Comment: Could you check if there's anything extra in your compile sources?

Comment: it works perfectly when I put your code in mine, please cross verify, there must be some duplication

Comment: Comment `AppDelegate` and see if it's compiling.

Comment: @AatishMolasi You mean the same `AppDelegate.swift` file compiled twice?

Comment: If you are sure you don't have a duplicate, then it's one of the famous Xcode bugs. Clean your project, restart Xcode, restart your Mac. It's quite annoying and reminds me on the old MS-Windows times, but it's often the only thing that "just works" :-)

Comment: @ZaidPathan when I Comment the AppDelegate, I only get this error `Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1`

Comment: @KrisRoofe, Go your project root directory->Build phases. Under `complied resources`, check AppDelegate file is added twice or not.

Comment: @pkc456 Yeah there is two AppDelegate there, and refer to the same file. Thank you.

Comment: I ran accross the same error in a Flutter app and there were not duplicate files but rather duplicate code in files with different names. If any other Flutter devs run into this, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67654264/3291390).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Go your project root directory->Build phases.
- Under complied resources, check AppDelegate file is added twice or not.

If it is added twice, then added one file.

Answer (score 3):

I add this answer as a supplement of pkc456's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50148473/6521116).

Both [redeclaration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27474798/6521116) and [recompile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50148125/6521116) can cause the issue.

In my code there is no redeclaration, so it's the recompile cause it.

I go to the *Build phases* menu, and I found the AppDelegate.swift file added twice there.

[image]

**Solution:**

1. Select either of the two AppDelegate.swift file, and click the <kbd>-</kbd> to remove it.
2. Clean and build the project(For *Xcode Version 9.3 (9E145)* Product->Clean and Product->Build).