# Invalid redeclaration of 'SwiftEntryPlugin'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flutter

I developed a flutter app on an Ubuntu machine and it works without problems on Android. Now I am trying to run it on iOS from a Mac but when I start debugging, I get several errors like the following:

```
/opt/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/entry-0.0.2_2/ios/Classes/SwiftAnimateInPlugin.swift:4:14: error: invalid redeclaration of 'SwiftEntryPlugin'
public class SwiftEntryPlugin: NSObject, Flutter Plugin {
             ^
```

`flutter doctor` passes for Flutter, Xcode, and Connected device.

- Flutter 2.2.0 - channel stable
- Tools - Dart 2.13.0

I have checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50148125/3291390) but they are not using Flutter and the answers are not relevant as far as I can tell. What would cause this error and how might I resolve it?

Comment: The answer in the link should be the one to be followed. This usually happens because you have duplicate files in your code. Grep for SwiftEntryPlugin: NSObject and check what all files are having that code. one of them should be a duplicate. This need not be particularly related to flutter.

Comment: @NisanthReddy I didn't have duplicate files but two files with different names happened to have duplicate code for whatever reason. I had been grepping for `SwiftEntryPlugin` which was returning too many results so your suggestion to grep with the `: NSObject` was helpful.

Comment: wonderful. glad to have helped:)

Answer (score 1):

Taking Nisanth Reddy's advice from the comment above and grepping for `SwiftEntryPlugin: NSObject` my search was narrowed down to 2 files. The files were `./my-app/ios/.symlinks/plugins/entry/ios/Classes/SwiftEntryPlugin.swift` and `./my-app/ios/.symlinks/plugins/entry/ios/Classes/SwiftAnimateInPlugin.swift`. After some trial and error, it seems like both files are required (the redundant one being required by a particular Flutter package I'm using, I think) but both had the exact same code in them so I removed all the code from one of the files but left the empty file sitting there in the directory and the problem was resolved.